# How do I use a variable in AppleScript (called from within Automator)

Tags: variables, applescript, automator

Instead of `"asdf"`, I want to use the `input` variable here.

Seems like this should be easy, but for some reason I can't figure it out.

```
on run {input, parameters}
-- Type 'asdf'
delay 1.900231
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "keystroke \"asdf\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
return input
end run

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
repeat
    try
        run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
    exit repeat
    on error errorMessage
        if ((current date) > endDate) then
            error "Can not " & uiScript
        end if
    end try
end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```

For example, if I try `set uiScript to "keystroke input"`, I get the error from Automator:

```
The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error.
Check the actionʼs properties and try running the workflow again.
```

Comment: `set uiScript to "keystroke \"" & input & "\""` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out myself. I feel dumb now.

`set uiScript to "keystroke \"" & input & "\""`